# randomForest: how to control the proportion of in-bag / out-of-bag samples?

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm using R `randomForest` for various regression tasks.  The hyperparameter tuning is still mysterious to me.  I've got a handle on tuning `ntree` and `mtry`, but it makes intuitive sense that I'd want to also tune the number of samples in each bag as an additional balance of model bias & variance.

Based on the documentation, I thought that this is what `sampsize` does.  But reading the function arguments reveals that it's more complicated than that.  If I run with replacement (`replace = TRUE`), it seems I have no control over the proportion of in-bag / out-of-bag samples.  In fact, with `replace = TRUE`, I don't think the proportion that the algorithm uses is even documented.

**Documentation**: `sampsize: Size(s) of sample to draw.`

**Function arguments**: `sampsize = if (replace) nrow(x) else ceiling(.632*nrow(x))`

Is there a way to control the proportion of in-bag-samples?  Is this even a worthwhile tuning parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `sampsize = if (replace) nrow(x) else ceiling(.632*nrow(x))` only means that its **default value** is `nrow(x)` when replace is true and `ceiling(.632*nrow(x))` otherwise.

However, you can change as you wish by assigning a value to it:

```
randomForest(X, replace = T, sampsize = 10)
```